# insert html into another page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Is it possible to insert or embbed html or even js scripts, into another html page using javascript. the purpose is to create a firefox add-on that would display alongside the actual content of the page some other external content.
For example:

```
    var pageMod = require("page-mod");
    pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.org",
    contentScriptWhen: 'end',
    contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
             ' "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";'
    });
```

This would simply display "page matches ruleset" everytime I would access a .org website, but instead I would like to add some content, without modifying the actual content of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the Greasemonkey Firefox addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

It lets your write your own scripts to do whatever you please with webpages.

Comment: Can I use Greasemonkey with the new add-on builder for firefox add-ons?

Comment: @DDD, I don't know about addon development, but I don't think you can include others' addons into your own. Maybe take a look at the source code of Greasemonkey to see how the allow you to add javascript to webpages: http://greasemonkey.mozdev.org/source.html